# How to delete a table rows and keep top X rows

Tags: python, mysql, database, large-data, rowdeleting

I have this large table in MySQL `incident_archive` that has millions of records, I want to sort the rows by `created` column and keep the Top X rows and delete the rest, what is the most efficient way to do this.

So far I came up with this solution in Python:

```
def do_delete_archive(rowsToKeep):

    if rowsToKeep > 0:
        db_name = find_environment_value('DB_NAME', False, "dbname")
        db_host = find_environment_value('DB_HOST', False, "host")
        db_user = find_environment_value('DB_USER', False, "username")
        db_pass = find_environment_value('DB_PASS', False, "password")
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host=db_host,user=db_user,passwd=db_pass,db=db_name)
        cursor = db.cursor()            
        
        sql = f"""DELETE FROM `incident_archive` 
                    WHERE incident_id NOT IN 
                    ( SELECT incident_id FROM 
                    ( SELECT incident_id FROM `incident_archive` ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT {rowsToKeep}) foo) LIMIT 10000;"""
        
        try:
            rowcount = rowsToKeep+ 1
            while rowcount > rowsToKeep:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                db.commit()
                rowcount = cursor.rowcount
                print(f"--- Affected Rows: {rowcount} ---")

        except:
            db.rollback()
```

The issue that I have here if `rowsToKeep` has value more or equal `10000` this approach will not work, what is a better way to this process?

**Note: rowsToKeep value is dynamic, meaning it can change.

Comment: A better way to do this is with partitioning by date. Then you can just delete the oldest partition.

Comment: @Barmar I just read about partitioning  how can I keep the top X rows and delete the oldest partition, can you explain more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093585/how-to-partition-a-table-by-datetime-column

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/partitioning-and-freeing-disk-space

Comment: I looked at those links but still cant see how this can help my situation.

Comment: You don't keep the top X rows. You partition by date range, then use `ALTER TABLE` to remove the oldest partition and add a new partition for the current time range.

Comment: E.g. a partition for every week or month.

Comment: top X is the important part in my question I want my table have X rows after this code has ran that are the latest `created` rows in my table.

Comment: Sorry, then partitioning isn't helpful.

Comment: the X (rowsToKeep) comes from a configuration file in my application, which defines that table should always have X amount of rows

Comment: Aren't you getting an error from that query? It should fail because of `Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: I ran this code, I dont get error.

Comment: `LIMIT rowsToKeep` should be `LIMIT {rowsToKeep}` so the variable is substituted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with solution below:

NOTE: threshold is the variable contains number of max records we want to keep 1000 in my example

```
sqlCreate = f"""CREATE TABLE new_incident_archive LIKE incident_archive;"""
print(f"Running query is: {sqlCreate}")
cursor.execute(sqlCreate)
print(f"Done with: {sqlCreate}")

sqlInsert = f"""INSERT INTO new_incident_archive SELECT * FROM `incident_archive` ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT {threshold}"""
print(f"Running query is: {sqlInsert}")
cursor.execute(sqlInsert)
db.commit()
print(f"Done with: {sqlInsert}")

sqlDrop = f"""DROP TABLE incident_archive"""
print(f"Running query is: {sqlDrop}")
cursor.execute(sqlDrop)
print(f"Done with: {sqlDrop}")

sqlRename = f"""RENAME TABLE `new_incident_archive` TO `incident_archive`;"""
print(f"Running query is: {sqlRename}")
cursor.execute(sqlRename)
print(f"Done with: {sqlRename}")
```