# How to query all tables data available in MySQL database using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to the node.js script I want to calculate the sum of Distance column where the Distance column is available in every table in database before I used looping through tables but it takes so much time to give every table result, is there any method to fetch result fast.
this is the sample code which I am using for individual table selection now I want for all tables

```
app.post('/fetch-data', (req, res) => {
   const selectedTable = req.body.table;
   const dateTimeRange = req.body.dateTimeRange;
   const [fromDateTime, toDateTime] = dateTimeRange.split(' - ');
   const fromDateTimeObj = new Date(fromDateTime);
   const toDateTimeObj = new Date(toDateTime);
   const fromDateTimeSQL = fromDateTimeObj.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
   const toDateTimeSQL = toDateTimeObj.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');  // querying database and fetching data based on selected table and selected date
   const fetchDataQuery = `SELECT * FROM \`${selectedTable}\`WHERE date_time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE(?, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');`;
   const getTableNamesQuery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'ingodata';";
   pool.query(getTableNamesQuery, (err, results) => {
       if (err) {
           console.error('Error fetching table names:', err);
           return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching table names' });
       }
       const tableNames = results.map((row) => row.TABLE_NAME);

   });
   pool.query(fetchDataQuery, [fromDateTimeObj, toDateTimeObj], (err, results) => {
       if (err) {
           console.error(`Error fetching data from ${selectedTable}:`, err);
           return res.status(500).send(`Error fetching data from ${selectedTable}`);
       }
       if (!results || results.length === 0) {
           // Handle the case when no data is found
           const noDataHtml = `
           <h1>No data found for the selected date range.</h1>
           `;
           return res.send(noDataHtml);
       }
const data = results;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Looping through the tables is not something you should be doing in a regular query.

Comment: from the above code calculates and gives the data based on single table selection, but i want the sum of Distance column for every table available in a database each and every Distance value has to be stored in array, with looping i can able to achieve but it takes too much time to display the result, is there any possible way to get the result at a short period of time

Comment: Without knowing how many tables you have, their strucure, etc, and what you mean exactly by "takes so much time" it's hard to tell if it's a normal timing or if there is a problem with your code. From what I know about SQL, i doubt a query aggregating all the tables result in a single query would speed up the process, you probably have better performance querying each table separately like you do already. A change in tables structure may be needed for better performances SQL wise

Comment: I have 170 tables in my database, each and every table has same column names, and i want the sum of the Distance value from Distance column from every table  based on the date range selection

Comment: Having 170 separate tables with exactly the same structure seems like an anti-pattern to me, it would be interesting to know why this design. From what you are trying to achieve it looks like you want to treat them as a single table, can we know which engine is used for these tables? (Innodb, MyIsam, etc?)

Comment: this 170 tables having 170  electric vehicles data, IOT device sending data like voltage, distance, Ignition on/off data for every vehicle in that I want to calculate the sum of Distance  for every vehicle i just want to see the Top 5 vehicles which is covering max distance

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can do to calculate sums of distance and query it for every table.

1. Instead of using for loop to loop over table names and use
   Promise.all(Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)). It will call all the promises
   nearly together which will drop total query time. While using for
   loop it's sequential, meaning 1 async request will wait for another.
   But for that you will have to promisify callback functions since
   Promise.all accepts array of promises. You can read more on how to
   promisify callback function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises). pros -> It is relatively
   small change for your current code and if you have small datasets,
   it may be right solution for you. cons-> Does not scale well,
   if your dataset is big, querying some of distance maybe even issue
   in 1 table, let alone on every table and in nearly same time. Can
   potentially cause slow queries and even timeouts and db overloading.
2. Create new table where you will save total distance for each of the table. So you would have columns like total_distance_table_a, total_distance_table_b and etc... If distance updates in one of the tables, you would also update it in real time here. This way you will be making only 1 query to get all your totals. This will simplify your code, dramatically reduce load on database and greatly increase average query time.

I would recommend 2nd approach, since it simplifies your code and scales much better than your looping over tables and querying total distance from them

Comment: i think the 2nd approach won't work for me, based on date range i want to sum the Distance column for every table

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code there are a number of areas for improvement:

1. Using `SELECT *`  reads and returns all columns. See if you can select only the columns you need, or aggregate them at the db already, e.g. `Select SUM(distance) ...`
2. Interating over ALL tables sounds like a bad idea. DBs are optimized to iterate over rows. If you really need to split your data over several tables, [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) may be useful to logically split data. See answers [here on how to partition a table by a datetme column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093585/how-to-partition-a-table-by-datetime-column)
3. You can explore using a cache table (or stored view) to speed up your queries. The cache is optimized for quick lookups and is updated whenever base tables are updated. [Window functions may come useful.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) However, I would explore caching only when #1-2 are fixed.